# Number list in cgridview fail in Yii

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I want to fix the repetitive number list problem in my gridview which every page the number list is always 1 untill 10 such as picture below.

[image]

Then I've search some tutorial and try this code below.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
                        'id'=>'publikasi-grid',
                        'itemsCssClass' => 'items2',
                        'dataProvider'=>$model->searchARC(),
                        ....
                        ....
                        'columns'=>array(
                            array(
                                    'header'=>'No.',
                                    'type'=>'raw',
                                    //'value'=> function ($this, $row){ return $row+1; },                                   
                                    'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align: center;','class'=>'nomor'),
                                    'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align: center;','class'=>'nomor'),
                                    'value'=>'$this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->currentPage * $this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->pageSize + ($row+1)',
                            ),
                       .....
```

And it fail to appear.

Is there something wrong with my code or is there any way around this?

-Thnks-